# Extract filename from path string

Tags: filenames, string

I have a string like so

```
/path/to/some/file.txt
```

I want to extract only the file's name, without extension:

```
file
```

The problem is that this path is chosen randomly and I can't hardcode it into a variable as path, it must be string.
I don't expect file's name to contain any non-alphanumeric characters. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: In what form do you have this string? Is it in a shell variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:** 
Check out the answer here on stack overflow using basename
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124347/879882

```
basename /path/to/some/file.txt
```

will return just the file name. 
More can be read at `man basename`

If you are looking to have just the file name without having the suffix, you can just complete an `basename -s .txt /path/to/some/file.txt` and it will also drop the suffix.

**Another option:**  
You could do an `awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}`
and for this option of being able to drop the suffix, just `| awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} {print $1}'`

Comment: Also, worth to mention dirname, which in turn extracts the directory name (strips the file name).